# How to count the elements in a Numpy stride-tricks blocks?

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on numpy stride-tricks non-overlapping blocks which are generated from an image of size 400x400. So to get 40x40 blocks out of the image, the size of individual blocks will be 10x10 pixels and hence, the last pixel of the image would read something like this- [39,39,9,9]. Now, the problem is that I want to count the no. of complete white blocks i.e. if in a block all 10x10 pixels are 255, it'll be a white block, so then the count of while-blocks go up. I am using a very simple but costly in terms of time consumption code for this :

```
    blocks = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(image, shape=shape, strides=strides)    
    counter = 0 ##### Counting the white blocks
    for i in range(40): 
        for j in range(40):
          c = 0
          for k in range(10):
             for l in range(10):
                if blocks[i,j,k,l] ==255:
                  c = c + 1
           if c ==100:
              counter = counter +1
```

Is there a pretty and an efficient way to do this?? Or any available in-built function that will be helpful for this? This piece of code takes really long time compared to the rest of my code, so I need a work-around for it...plz help..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your blocks are not overlapping, so there is no real risk of generating huge intermediate arrays. Simply call `np.all` over the last two axes of a boolean array comparing your image to 255

```
np.count_nonzero((blocks == 255).all(axis=(-1, -2)))
```

If you are using numpy < 1.7 then you would have to do:

```
np.count_nonzero((blocks == 255).all(axis=-2).all(axis=-1))
```

Comment: Hi Jamie coll trick, say does this axis=( a1, a2 ) also work on other numpy functions? why did you choose the values negative?

Comment: The negative axis indices indicate they are the last and second to last, `axis=(2, 3)` would be the exact same in your case. All of the reduction ufuncs, e.g. `sum`, `prod`, `mean`,..., can take an `axis` argument.

Comment: Thanks, that is great to know. Can you tell me (us) if that is internally also more efficient than doing it in the pre numpy 1.7 style?

Comment: Yes, because the alternative is to chain several calls to a single axis reduction, and each creates an intermediate array. When calling with multiple axes, the final result is generated in a single shot, without those intermediate ones.